# Comparing items in large list - finding items differing in 1 letter by length - Python

Tags: python, regex, string, list, levenshtein-distance

I am looking to solve a problem I've been stuck on in Python. I have a single file, with one column, which contains approx. 6,000 lines. For each line, every item is unique (this file was filtered to remove duplicates froma 40,000 line file). The items in each row vary in length, where some are equal in length to others.

An example of a single line:

```
IGHV3-30/33rn-IGHJ4-CARDPSLSSMITFGGVIVTRGYFDYW
```

Or more examples with tab separated after third "-" (differing first parts):

```
IGHV3-23-IGHJ4  CAKDRGYTGYGVYFDYW
IGHV4-39-IGHJ4  CARHDILTGYSYYFDYW
IGHV3-23-IGHJ3  CAKSGGWYLSDAFDIW
IGHV4-39-IGHJ4  CARTGFGELGFDYW
IGHV1-2-IGHJ2   CARDSDYDWYFDLW
IGHV1-8-IGHJ3   CARGQTYYDILTGPSDAFDIW
IGHV4-39-IGHJ5  CARSTGDWFDPW
IGHV3-9-IGHJ3   CANVPIYSSSYDAFDIW
IGHV3-23-IGHJ4  CAKDWELYYFDYW
IGHV3-23-IGHJ4  CAKDRGYTGFGVYFDYW
IGHV4-39-IGHJ4  CARHLGYNNSWYPFDYW
IGHV1-2-IGHJ4   CAREGYNWNDEGRFDYW
IGHV3-23-IGHJ3  CAKSSGWYLSDAFDIW
IGHV4-39-IGHJ4  CARYLGYNSNWYPFDYW
IGHV3-23-IGHJ6  CAKEGCSSGCPYYYYGMDVW
IGHV3-23-IGHJ3  CAKWGPDAFDIW
IGHV3-11-IGHJ   CATSGGSP
IGHV3-11-IGHJ4  CARDGDGYNDYW
IGHV1-2-IGHJ4   CARRIGYSSGSEDYW
IGHV1-2-IGHJ4   CARDIAVPGHGDYW
IGHV6-1-IGHJ4   CASGGAVPGYYFDYW
```

In the first column, there are some items that are different. In the second column every item is the unique. The first column items need to match, and then the second column items need to be sorted by a minimum mismatch of 2. 
 Ideally this would be good to do with Levenshtein module since I can put the max, but I need two strings. Is there a way to use Levenshtein on every item in a single list?

What I need to do is open this file (I think sorting it by length first may help, however I'm not sure). After all the items are grouped by length, I need to sort these items into groups that differ by 1 character (the strings before the third "-" need to be identical, where the string after the "-" should differ only by 1 char.)

I think the problem I'm having is in regards to generating a proper for loop to iterate over the items length.

The code I have thus far:

```
import sys
import os
import Levenshtein

inp = sys.argv[1] # Input file containing single column of items

with open(inp, "r") as f1:
        vj = [line.strip() for line in f1]

lengths = []
for k in vj:
        i = len(k)
        lengths.append(i)

lengths_sort = sorted(lengths, reverse = True)

uniq_len = []
for i in lengths_sort:
       if i not in uniq_len:
                uniq_len.append(i)

print uniq_len #For QC purposes

def get_new_list(strings, counts, outlist=[]):
        for s in strings:
                if len(s) == counts[0]:
                        outlist.append(s)
        return outlist

new_vj = get_new_list(vj, uniq_len, outlist=[])
print new_vj
ham = Levenshtein.hamming(new_vj[0], new_vj[1])
print ham
```

So the output I was looking for is good, but not yet complete:

```
[46, 44, 43, 42, 41, 40, 39, 38, 37, 36, 35, 34, 33, 32, 31, 30, 29, 28, 27, 26, 25, 24, 23, 22, 21, 20, 19, 18]
46
['IGHV3-30/33rn-IGHJ4-CAKDPSLSSMITFGGVIVTRGYFDYW', 'IGHV3-30/33rn-IGHJ4-CARDPSLSSMITFGGVIVTRGYFDYW']
1
```

There are two items of length 46 (coincidentally the strings before the third "-" is the same; great) and they differ by only one character between the two strings.

My trouble is, 1. how can I iterate through the numbers in the uniq_len list as unput for matching length in the "strings" list (see function in code). 2. I want to create a new list for each differing length. 3. If there are multiple items in each new list, all items much differ by only 1 character.

Note: The "-"'s were creating using UNIX paste -d- command with 3 files containing 1 column each to create this file. Would it be easier to paste these files together with a \t as the delimiter to create 3 columns?

So, open the file, strip the lines, and one can then match up the 1st column, 2nd column, and see if the third column differs by one or more characters?

All help is appreciated.

Comment: do you want to find strings that have *length* different by one, or strings that differ by one *character*.  IE: "abc"/"abcd", and "abc"/"abx".

Comment: strings that are equal in length, and differ by one character. i want to create new lists for each length that differ by 1. I would do this again for 2,3,4 and so on, until there are no more items left.

Comment: Your code references a variable named `v` in a couple of places. What is it? You also refer to the "items" (in each line I think) -- do you mean the groups of characters delimited by "-" characters?

Comment: the v's were typos. I believe i corrected the errors. When I refer to an "item", I mean the entire line. So, yea the group of charcters delimited by "-". As I mentioned, the strings in the input file were created using unix paste from other single column files. Ideally, perhaps it owuld be best to use a single file with two columns. Ex: IGHV3-30/33rn-IGHJ4 \t CARDPSLSSMITFGGVIVTRGYFDYW. The items in the first column need to match for items in the second column to be first considered by length, and then a mismatch charcter of max 1.

Comment: Would you please provide some additional sample data (with both items of the same and differing lengths)?

Comment: I've edited the examples in my original code

Comment: That helped some, but I wish you hadn't preprocessed the data and instead showed in in raw form and showed lines where there first part wasn't all the same. Furthermore I don't see _any_ bold characters in it much less "two bolded AA's". That's because markd Lastly, where exactly are you stuck -- and what do you want to know? I think Python can easily process your data, but I'm still unsure about both the format of the input data and what exactly what you want your script to accomplish that it doesn't already.

Comment: I've added raw data. WHen i clicked to bold the characters to in the previous edit, it placed double **'s aroudn the character. What I want to know for the output, is what is shown. However, it is only a coincidence that two are of length 46 and they differ only by one AA.

Comment: `new_vj[0]` and `new_vj[1]` don't appear to differ at all -- `['IGHV3-30/33rn-IGHJ4-CAKDPSLSSMITFGGVIVTRGYFDYW', 'IGHV3-30/33rn-IGHJ4-CARDPSLSSMITFGGVIVTRGYFDYW']` -- so I don't know what you mean by "they differ only by one AA".

Comment: they differ in the third position. CAK and CAR. Everything prior to the third "-" is identical, as it should be.

Comment: Ah, I think I get it now, you didn't mean they differed by the letter "A" in some position, but rather one of their amino acids was different. Sorry, I'm just a dumb CS major taking things very literally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** Modified to handle a variable number of "id" sub-fields and print the results as a single string. Note several test cases were added to the end of the input to have some with a different number of leading fields making up the id (i.e. 2 instead of 3).

I also renamed the`num_mismatches()`function`hamming_distance()`because that's what it is.

Using the following input:

```
IGHV3-23-IGHJ4-CAKDRGYTGYGVYFDYW
IGHV4-39-IGHJ4-CARHDILTGYSYYFDYW
IGHV3-23-IGHJ3-CAKSGGWYLSDAFDIW
IGHV4-39-IGHJ4-CARTGFGELGFDYW
IGHV1-2-IGHJ2-CARDSDYDWYFDLW
IGHV1-8-IGHJ3-CARGQTYYDILTGPSDAFDIW
IGHV4-39-IGHJ5-CARSTGDWFDPW
IGHV3-9-IGHJ3-CANVPIYSSSYDAFDIW
IGHV3-23-IGHJ4-CAKDWELYYFDYW
IGHV3-23-IGHJ4-CAKDRGYTGFGVYFDYW
IGHV4-39-IGHJ4-CARHLGYNNSWYPFDYW
IGHV1-2-IGHJ4-CAREGYNWNDEGRFDYW
IGHV3-23-IGHJ3-CAKSSGWYLSDAFDIW
IGHV4-39-IGHJ4-CARYLGYNSNWYPFDYW
IGHV3-23-IGHJ6-CAKEGCSSGCPYYYYGMDVW
IGHV3-23-IGHJ3-CAKWGPDAFDIW
IGHV3-11-IGHJ-CATSGGSP
IGHV3-11-IGHJ4-CARDGDGYNDYW
IGHV1-2-IGHJ4-CARRIGYSSGSEDYW
IGHV1-2-IGHJ4-CARDIAVPGHGDYW
IGHV6-1-IGHJ4-CASGGAVPGYYFDYW
IGHV1-2-CAREGYNWNDEGRFDYW
IGHV4-39-CARSTGDWFDPW
IGHV1-2-CARDSDYDWYFDLW
```

and this script:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import izip, tee
import os
import sys

# http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance#Algorithm_example
def hamming_distance(s1, s2):
    """ Count number of mismatched characters in equal length strings. """
    if not isinstance(s1, basestring): raise ValueError('s1 is not a string')
    if not isinstance(s2, basestring): raise ValueError('s2 is not a string')
    if len(s1) != len(s2): raise ValueError('string lengths do not match')
    return sum(a != b for a, b in izip(s1, s2))

def pairwise(iterable):  # itertools recipe
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return izip(a, b)

inp = sys.argv[1]  # Input file

unique = defaultdict(list)
with open(inp, 'rb') as file:
    for fields in (line.strip().split('-') for line in file):
        id = '-'.join(fields[:-1])  # recombine all but last field into an id
        unique[id].append(fields[-1])  # accumulate ending fields with same id

for id in sorted(unique):
    final_fields = unique[id]
    final_fields.sort(key=lambda field: len(field))  # sort by length
    print id + ':' + '-'.join(final_fields)
    if len(final_fields) > 1:  # at least one pair to compare for mismatches?
        for a, b in pairwise(final_fields):
            if len(a) == len(b) and hamming_distance(a, b) < 2:
                print '  {!r} and {!r} differ by < 2 characters'.format(a, b)
```

Output:

```
IGHV1-2:CARDSDYDWYFDLW-CAREGYNWNDEGRFDYW
IGHV1-2-IGHJ2:CARDSDYDWYFDLW
IGHV1-2-IGHJ4:CARDIAVPGHGDYW-CARRIGYSSGSEDYW-CAREGYNWNDEGRFDYW
IGHV1-8-IGHJ3:CARGQTYYDILTGPSDAFDIW
IGHV3-11-IGHJ:CATSGGSP
IGHV3-11-IGHJ4:CARDGDGYNDYW
IGHV3-23-IGHJ3:CAKWGPDAFDIW-CAKSGGWYLSDAFDIW-CAKSSGWYLSDAFDIW
  'CAKSGGWYLSDAFDIW' and 'CAKSSGWYLSDAFDIW' differ by < 2 characters
IGHV3-23-IGHJ4:CAKDWELYYFDYW-CAKDRGYTGYGVYFDYW-CAKDRGYTGFGVYFDYW
  'CAKDRGYTGYGVYFDYW' and 'CAKDRGYTGFGVYFDYW' differ by < 2 characters
IGHV3-23-IGHJ6:CAKEGCSSGCPYYYYGMDVW
IGHV3-9-IGHJ3:CANVPIYSSSYDAFDIW
IGHV4-39:CARSTGDWFDPW
IGHV4-39-IGHJ4:CARTGFGELGFDYW-CARHDILTGYSYYFDYW-CARHLGYNNSWYPFDYW-CARYLGYNSNWYPFDYW
IGHV4-39-IGHJ5:CARSTGDWFDPW
IGHV6-1-IGHJ4:CASGGAVPGYYFDYW
```

Hope this update is also helpful...

Comment: Ok. In order for the items to be considered for mismatches, they must first match in the first three values: "IGHV3", "23", "IGHJ4 from your second example. The fourth value, is the primary value in which to look for mismatches, based on length first. So, the program should sort by the first 3 fields, then by length of the fourth field (previously done using all fields concatenated), and then identify and group by number of mismatches < 2 (in fourth field)

Comment: BTW, you might want to change the step where the `unique` dict is first built to avoid adding duplicate fourth fields. Also, there's probably a better name for the 4th field -- like `aa_sequence` or something.

Comment: Yes it does. Thanks Martineau.

Comment: Martineau, I've up-voted and accepted the answer. The original dataset from which this snippet was taken also contains 2 or 4 "-"'s, and not always 3. I was able to modify the code to account for that. I have a question regarding the code. What if there are outliers, one's that match the first two fields, but differ greater than 2? I want to also be able to determine how many are < 2 similarity if the first two fields match, and how many are > 2 if the first two fields match.

Comment: Actually the code in my answer assumes there are always **4** "fields", so some of what you wrote doesn't make sense to me. Regardless, rather than recombine the fields that make up what I called the "id", you could keep them separated as an n-tuple of values and still be able to use them as dictionary keys. That way you would be able to also write code that did things differently depending on how many of the id "sub-fields" matched.

Comment: Your edit was rejected after review by both myself and two others. One of the reasons was that it was invalid because you can't mix tabs and spaces in Python code like that. Another is that it was too radical of a change to my answer. If you want to do something like this please ask another question or put (valid) modified code in another answer to your own question (you can do that here). Meanwhile I will take a look at what you did assuming I can get the indenting straightened-out.

Comment: Martineau, thanks for the note on the edit. The tabs and spaces must have been an error in pasting the code. Nevertheless, it worked the way I wanted. There are some parts of your code I'm unsure of how they work. For you first print statement: print id, field4s. How can this be modified to print to a single column in a new file? And then another new file for ea id there after.

Comment: How would you like to combine the `id` and multiple `field4s` values into a single item/column?

Comment: For each id, instead of printing the field4s into a list, print them as a single column with the id as the header. One column/id per file: id_1.txt..id_2.txt (named by id). The results of the pairswise function, for the next print statement can be printed to another file for each id (id_1_pairs.txt..id_2_pairs.txt..) I've been attempting to edit your code, however I can't get it to "strip" the list characters ('[]').

Comment: Try something like `id + '??'.join(field4s)` where `'??'` is the string you'd like put between each `field4s` value.

Comment: Your edit also left out the definition of `unique = defaultdict(list)` before appending values to `unique[id]` lists.

Comment: another pasting error. I only pasted starting at "with".

Comment: I think it would be possible to handle a variable number of id fields in a simpler way. I'll post an update to my answer showing what I mean. This will likely be my last comment at least for now.

Comment: The `num_mismatches()` function (now renamed `hamming_distance()`) most definitely counts the number of characters that don't match in equal length strings -- I tested it -- however they must be _in the same relative position_.

Comment: ['CARERRFFDYW'] and ['CARDHMYYDYVWGSFRPPHAFDIW'] differ by < 2 characters. There certainly differ greater than 2, as there lengths are not equal. If you mean in the same relative position, all characters contained in the first sequence are in the second. However this is incorrect.

Comment: In the cases in your comment before last, all but the second pair of strings are different length so the function would raise an exception if you passed them to it. The two strings in the second case are the same length and their hamming distance is < 2. Same relative position means for position `i` that `a[i]` must equal `b[i]` or it's counted as a mismatch. In your immediately preceding comment those are both **lists** of length 1, the string in each one is not the same length as the other. I think you may be passing the `hamming_distance()` function 2 lists of strings instead of 2 strings.

Comment: I'm not sure why that was the case. When I use the code you have now, everything works perfectly. The fields with the id's may be a huge list, but those that have the same id and differ by less than two AA within their sequence are printed. Sorry for the confusion. Thank you Martineau, for all your help and time. I greatly appreciate it.

Comment: No problem. I noticed in your attempted edit that you were appending [_slices_](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html?highlight=slice) to the `unique[id]` lists not single strings, and a slice of a list is still a list even if it only has only one (or even no-) thing in it. You probably just need to become more adept using Python.

Comment: One final thing. You function pairwise looks like it iterates over the items sequentially as commented (0,1)(1,2)(2,1)..How can this be changed to use all combinations, if their lengths are equal? There are some that do differ in < 2 positions, however they are skipped b/c the latter may be seen later in the input. I suspect itertools.combinations(iterable, r) would be the appropriate solution?

Comment: You can probably use `itertools.combinations()` but the tricky part will be passing it the proper portions of `final_fields` -- specifically groups of strings in it of the same length. I would suggest using [`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html?highlight=groupby#itertools.groupby) to accomplish that.

Answer (score 0):

Let assume that you want to sort some lines by A) length of column, B) Levenshtein distance of that column vs the col above or below.

The issue immediately arrises that levenshtein distance is between 2 relative objects; ie, `Levenshtein(a, b)` not a mono property like `len(a)`. The value of the levenshtein distance changes as the lines in the list change in position relative to each other.

Python 2.X supports the older `cmp` versus `key` argument for sort. It is inefficient, since it must be reevaluated every pass through the sort. However, Levenshtein sort is relative to the item above and below the entry.

As an example, lets make a matrix of your example data:

```
txt='''\
IGHV3-23-IGHJ4  CAKDRGYTGYGVYFDYW
IGHV4-39-IGHJ4  CARHDILTGYSYYFDYW
IGHV3-23-IGHJ3  CAKSGGWYLSDAFDIW
IGHV4-39-IGHJ4  CARTGFGELGFDYW
IGHV1-2-IGHJ2   CARDSDYDWYFDLW
IGHV1-8-IGHJ3   CARGQTYYDILTGPSDAFDIW
IGHV4-39-IGHJ5  CARSTGDWFDPW
IGHV3-9-IGHJ3   CANVPIYSSSYDAFDIW
IGHV3-23-IGHJ4  CAKDWELYYFDYW
IGHV3-23-IGHJ4  CAKDRGYTGFGVYFDYW
IGHV4-39-IGHJ4  CARHLGYNNSWYPFDYW
IGHV1-2-IGHJ4   CAREGYNWNDEGRFDYW
IGHV3-23-IGHJ3  CAKSSGWYLSDAFDIW
IGHV4-39-IGHJ4  CARYLGYNSNWYPFDYW
IGHV3-23-IGHJ6  CAKEGCSSGCPYYYYGMDVW
IGHV3-23-IGHJ3  CAKWGPDAFDIW
IGHV3-11-IGHJ   CATSGGSP
IGHV3-11-IGHJ4  CARDGDGYNDYW
IGHV1-2-IGHJ4   CARRIGYSSGSEDYW
IGHV1-2-IGHJ4   CARDIAVPGHGDYW
IGHV6-1-IGHJ4   CASGGAVPGYYFDYW'''

data=[line.split() for line in txt.splitlines()] 
# [['IGHV3-23-IGHJ4', 'CAKDRGYTGYGVYFDYW'], ['IGHV4-39-IGHJ4', 'CARHDILTGYSYYFDYW'], ['IGHV3-23-IGHJ3', 'CAKSGGWYLSDAFDIW'], ['IGHV4-39-IGHJ4', 'CARTGFGELGFDYW'], ['IGHV1-2-IGHJ2', 'CARDSDYDWYFDLW'], ['IGHV1-8-IGHJ3', 'CARGQTYYDILTGPSDAFDIW'], ['IGHV4-39-IGHJ5', 'CARSTGDWFDPW'], ['IGHV3-9-IGHJ3', 'CANVPIYSSSYDAFDIW'], ['IGHV3-23-IGHJ4', 'CAKDWELYYFDYW'], ['IGHV3-23-IGHJ4', 'CAKDRGYTGFGVYFDYW'], ['IGHV4-39-IGHJ4', 'CARHLGYNNSWYPFDYW'], ['IGHV1-2-IGHJ4', 'CAREGYNWNDEGRFDYW'], ['IGHV3-23-IGHJ3', 'CAKSSGWYLSDAFDIW'], ['IGHV4-39-IGHJ4', 'CARYLGYNSNWYPFDYW'], ['IGHV3-23-IGHJ6', 'CAKEGCSSGCPYYYYGMDVW'], ['IGHV3-23-IGHJ3', 'CAKWGPDAFDIW'], ['IGHV3-11-IGHJ', 'CATSGGSP'], ['IGHV3-11-IGHJ4', 'CARDGDGYNDYW'], ['IGHV1-2-IGHJ4', 'CARRIGYSSGSEDYW'], ['IGHV1-2-IGHJ4', 'CARDIAVPGHGDYW'], ['IGHV6-1-IGHJ4', 'CASGGAVPGYYFDYW']]
```

Now sort those rows on length of `row[1]`:

```
data.sort(key=lambda l: len(l[1]))
```

Now sort based on the levenshtein distance of the entries. Note that you need to use `cmp` since levenstein is based on two values:

```
data.sort(cmp=levenshtein)

# [['IGHV3-11-IGHJ', 'CATSGGSP'], ['IGHV4-39-IGHJ5', 'CARSTGDWFDPW'], ['IGHV3-23-IGHJ3', 'CAKWGPDAFDIW'], ['IGHV3-11-IGHJ4', 'CARDGDGYNDYW'], ['IGHV3-23-IGHJ4', 'CAKDWELYYFDYW'], ['IGHV4-39-IGHJ4', 'CARTGFGELGFDYW'], ['IGHV1-2-IGHJ2', 'CARDSDYDWYFDLW'], ['IGHV1-2-IGHJ4', 'CARDIAVPGHGDYW'], ['IGHV1-2-IGHJ4', 'CARRIGYSSGSEDYW'], ['IGHV6-1-IGHJ4', 'CASGGAVPGYYFDYW'], ['IGHV3-23-IGHJ3', 'CAKSGGWYLSDAFDIW'], ['IGHV3-23-IGHJ3', 'CAKSSGWYLSDAFDIW'], ['IGHV3-23-IGHJ4', 'CAKDRGYTGYGVYFDYW'], ['IGHV4-39-IGHJ4', 'CARHDILTGYSYYFDYW'], ['IGHV3-9-IGHJ3', 'CANVPIYSSSYDAFDIW'], ['IGHV3-23-IGHJ4', 'CAKDRGYTGFGVYFDYW'], ['IGHV4-39-IGHJ4', 'CARHLGYNNSWYPFDYW'], ['IGHV1-2-IGHJ4', 'CAREGYNWNDEGRFDYW'], ['IGHV4-39-IGHJ4', 'CARYLGYNSNWYPFDYW'], ['IGHV3-23-IGHJ6', 'CAKEGCSSGCPYYYYGMDVW'], ['IGHV1-8-IGHJ3', 'CARGQTYYDILTGPSDAFDIW']]
```

If you want to change the two element sort `cmp` to a key type (for Python 3 that does not support cmp), you can produce comparison objects:

```
def cmp_to_key(mycmp):
    'Convert a cmp= function into a key= function'
    class K(object):
        def __init__(self, obj, *args):
            self.obj = obj
        def __lt__(self, other):
            return mycmp(self.obj, other.obj) < 0
        def __gt__(self, other):
            return mycmp(self.obj, other.obj) > 0
        def __eq__(self, other):
            return mycmp(self.obj, other.obj) == 0
        def __le__(self, other):
            return mycmp(self.obj, other.obj) <= 0
        def __ge__(self, other):
            return mycmp(self.obj, other.obj) >= 0
        def __ne__(self, other):
            return mycmp(self.obj, other.obj) != 0
    return K
```

The you call sort using `data.sort(key=cmp_to_key(levenshtein))`